# how to use viewmodel by ktx?

Tags: android, kotlin, generics

I want to use it like the official website
`val viewModel by viewModels { SavedStateViewModelFactory(application, this) }`

---

Yes, it's much simpler than using `ViewModelProvider...`

---

We all know that a ViewModel can be encapsulated in a basefragment, so I want to know how to encapsulate it by  `by viewmodels`.

---

I tried to encapsulate basefragment, but I had a problem with generics

---

just like as follow:
my baseFragment:

```
abstract class AbsFragment444<DB :ViewDataBinding, VM :ViewModel> :Fragment(){ 

    ***//other var
    ***//other var
    ***//other var

      
    protected  val mViewModel: VM by    viewModels(this,SavedStateViewModelFactory(requireActivity().application,this))
}
```

However, the compiler prompts: `cannot use 'VM' as modified type parameter. Use a class instead`

What should I do?

Comment: Try this line of code 
 abstract val viewModel: Class<VM>

Comment: I tried it ,then the compiler prompts in viewModels :```Type parameter bound for VM in inline fun <reified VM : ViewModel> Fragment.viewModels(noinline ownerProducer: () -> ViewModelStoreOwner = ..., noinline factoryProducer: (() -> ViewModelProvider.Factory)? = ...): Lazy<VM>
 is not satisfied: inferred type Class<VM> is not a subtype of ViewModel```

Comment: `by viewModels` has to know the concrete type that it is instantiating. Since your abstract class can't know that, it's not possible.

Comment: thanks,now i changed it to 'ViewModelProvider...'